# Coefficients in the sum $\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\sum_{j=0}^{m}A_{j,m}(n-k)^jk^j=n^{2m+1}, \ m=1,2,....$

Tags: nt.number-theory, co.combinatorics, binomial-coefficients, exponential-sums

Consider a sum $$\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\sum_{j=0}^{m}A_{j,m}(n-k)^jk^j$$
which returns an odd power $n^{2m+1}$ of $n$, for $\ m=0,1,2,...$ given fixed $A_{0,m}, \ A_{1,m}, \ ..., \ A_{m,m}$. The coefficients $A_{0,m}, \ A_{1,m},....$ are solutions of system of equations (refer to [.txt-file](https://kolosovpetro.github.io/mathematica_codes/table_mathematica_m=1,12.txt) with mathematica codes for $m=1,2,...12$). Coefficients $A_{0,m}, \ A_{1,m},....$ are arranged to the [PDF-table](https://kolosovpetro.github.io/pdf/coefficients_of_polynomial.pdf). For example,
$$\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\sum_{j=0}^{2}A_{j,2}(n-k)^jk^j=\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}30k^2(n-k)^2+1=n^5$$
Our coefficients are closely related to  to coefficients $\beta_{mv}$ from C. Jordan [Calculus of Finite Differences](https://oeis.org/A002457/a002457_1.pdf), pp. 448 - 450.

**Question**: Could the coefficients $A_{0,m}, \ A_{1,m}, \ ..., \ A_{m,m}$ be reached in a recurrent way using $\beta_{mv}$? This question also can be stated as: does there exist such a function $f(\beta_{mv})=A_{v,m}$?

**Additional Question** How exactly are our coefficients $A_{0,m}, \ A_{1,m}, \ ..., \ A_{m,m}$ connected with $\beta_{mv}$?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**EDIT 2018-04-16**: Formulae are corrected.

I'm not sure about connection with $\beta_{mv}$, but we can obtain a recurrence formula for $A_{j,m}$ as follows.

First let us fix the unused values $A_{j,m}=0$ for $j<0$ or $j>m$, so we won't need to care about the summation range for $j$.

Expanding $(n-k)^j$ and using Faulhaber's formula, we get
$$\sum_{k=0}^{n-1} (n-k)^j k^j = \sum_{k=0}^{n-1} \sum_i \binom{j}i n^{j-i} (-1)^i k^{i+j}$$ 
$$=\sum_{i} \binom{j}{i} n^{j-i} \frac{(-1)^i}{i+j+1} \left[ \sum_t \binom{i+j+1}t B_t n^{i+j+1-t}  - B_{i+j+1}\right]$$
$$=\sum_{i,t} \binom{j}{i} \frac{(-1)^i}{i+j+1} \binom{i+j+1}t B_t n^{2j+1-t} - \sum_{i} \binom{j}{i}  \frac{(-1)^i}{i+j+1} B_{i+j+1} n^{j-i}$$
where $B_t$ are Bernoulli numbers.

Now, we notice that 
$$\sum_{i} \binom{j}{i} \frac{(-1)^i}{i+j+1} \binom{i+j+1}t
=\begin{cases}
\frac{1}{(2j+1)\binom{2j}j}, & \text{if } t=0;\\
\frac{(-1)^j}{t}\binom{j}{2j-t+1}, & \text{if } t>0.
\end{cases}
$$
In particular, the last sum is zero for $0<t\leq j$.

Hence, introducing $\ell=2j+1-t$ and $\ell=j-i$, respectively, we get
$$\sum_{k=0}^{n-1} (n-k)^j k^j
= \frac{1}{(2j+1)\binom{2j}j} n^{2j+1} + \sum_{\ell} \frac{(-1)^j}{2j+1-\ell}\binom{j}{\ell}B_{2j+1-\ell}n^{\ell} - \sum_{\ell} \binom{j}{\ell} \frac{(-1)^{j-\ell}}{2j+1-\ell} B_{2j+1-\ell}n^{\ell}$$
$$=\frac{1}{(2j+1)\binom{2j}j} n^{2j+1} + 2\sum_{\text{odd }\ell} \frac{(-1)^j}{2j+1-\ell}\binom{j}{\ell}B_{2j+1-\ell}n^{\ell}.$$

Using the definition of $A_{j,m}$, we obtain the following identity for polynomials in $n$:
$$(\star)\qquad\sum_{j} A_{j,m} \frac{1}{(2j+1)\binom{2j}j}n^{2j+1}  
+ 2 \sum_{j,\text{ odd }\ell} A_{j,m} \binom{j}{\ell} \frac{(-1)^j}{2j+1-\ell} B_{2j+1-\ell}n^{\ell} \equiv n^{2m+1}.$$

---

Taking the coefficient of $n^{2m+1}$ in $(\star)$, we get $A_{m,m} = (2m+1) \binom{2m}{m},$
and taking the coefficient of $x^{2d+1}$ for an integer $d$ in the range $m/2 \leq d < m$, we get $A_{d,m} = 0$.

Taking the coefficient of $n^{2d+1}$ in $(\star)$ for $m/4 \leq d < m/2$, we get 
$$A_{d,m} \frac{1}{(2d+1)\binom{2d}{d}} + 2 (2m+1) \binom{2m}{m} \binom{m}{2d+1} \frac{(-1)^m}{2m-2d} B_{2m-2d} = 0,$$
i.e.
$$A_{d,m} = (-1)^{m-1} \frac{(2m+1)!}{d!d!m!(m-2d-1)!}\frac{1}{m-d} B_{2m-2d}.$$

Continue similarly, we can express $A_{d,m}$ for each integer $d$ in the range $m/2^{s+1}\leq d< m/2^s$ (iterating consecutively $s=1,2,\dots$) via previously determined values of $A_{j,m}$ as follows:
$$A_{d,m} = (2d+1)\binom{2d}{d} \sum_{j\geq 2d+1} A_{j,m} \binom{j}{2d+1} \frac{(-1)^{j-1}}{j-d} B_{2j-2d}.$$
The same formula holds also for $d=0$.

Comment: thank you for your reply :) comment means to be very usefull

Comment: Dear Dr Alekseev, parhaps, do you see some connection between our $A_{j,m}$ and finite differences of power ? I asking because the zeros we have in [this table](https://kolosovpetro.github.io/pdf/coefficients_of_polynomial.pdf) seems to be like order of difference higher then power, i.e $D^m(x^n)=0, \ m>n$

Comment: I dont understand your notation "Taking the coefficient of $n^{2d+1}$ in (⋆) for $m/4 \leq d<m/2$" i thought $d$ should be an integer? $x^{2d+1}$ is miss-typos? So are the $d$ and $m$ integers or ? In core of question they are meant to be integers. If its not difficult and you have free time, show, please, application of your result on existing coefficients, from above table, thank you

Comment: can you show example for second row of [table](https://kolosovpetro.github.io/pdf/coefficients_of_polynomial.pdf), i.e reach coefficients $A_{0,2}=1, \ A_{1,2}=0, \ A_{2,2}=30$? thank you

Comment: @KolosovPetro: I've fixed errors in the formulae. Now, you should get the values from your table smoothly. E.g., for $m=2$, we first get $A_{2,2}=5\binom{4}{2}=30$. Then $A_{1,2} = 0$, and finally $$A_{0,2} = 1\binom{0}{0}\sum_{j\geq 1} A_{j,2} \binom{j}{1} \frac{(-1)^{j-1}}{j} B_{2j} = A_{2,2} 2 \frac{-1}{2} B_4 = 1.$$

Comment: Thank you for your detailed reply, now everything clear to me :)

Comment: @KolosovPetro: You are welcome. Please add your table of coefficients to the OEIS.

Comment: Yes, i will add ofcourse

Comment: https://oeis.org/A302971 OEIS sequence is finally accepted, thanks to everybody :)

Comment: Dear Dr. @max-alekseyev, i write a little questionnaire concerning to your answer, there i've written a few questions on changes i've added to your answer, check it please. The file available in [.tex](https://kolosovpetro.github.io/tex/TO_DR_ALEKSEYEV.tex) and [.pdf](https://kolosovpetro.github.io/pdf/TO_DR_ALEKSEYEV.pdf) formats. for your comfort, can you revise initial tex file if necessary and send me back? Thank you, after your answer i think i will finally understand everything :)

Comment: Petro - Let's take the discussion offline - drop me an email to maxal@gwu.edu

Comment: Done, mail sent from kolosovp94@gmail.com