# Coefficients $U_m(n,k)$ in the identity $n^{2m+1}=\sum\limits_{0\leq k \leq m}(-1)^{m-k}U_m(n,k)\cdot n^k$

Tags: nt.number-theory, co.combinatorics, polynomials, exponential-sums

Review the main result of [mathoverflow.net/questions/297900](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/297900/coefficients-in-the-sum-sum-k-0n-1-sum-j-0ma-j-mn-kjkj-n2m1), that is the identity
\begin{equation}\label{f1}
n^{2m+1}=\sum\limits_{1\leq k \leq n}\sum\limits_{j\geq0}A_{m,j}k^j(n-k)^j,
\end{equation}
where $A_{m,j}$ is from sequences [A302971](https://oeis.org/A302971) and [A304042](https://oeis.org/A304042).
In this question we discuss the polynomial
\begin{equation}\label{f2}
\sum\limits_{0\leq k \leq m}(-1)^{m-k}U_m(n,k)\cdot n^k, \ m\geq0 \ \mathrm{integer}
\end{equation}
That is generated by the identity
\begin{equation}\label{f3}
(1.3)\quad\sum\limits_{1\leq k \leq T}\sum\limits_{j\geq0}A_{m,j}k^j(n-k)^j=\sum\limits_{0\leq k \leq m}(-1)^{m-k}U_m(n,k)\cdot n^k,
\end{equation}
where $T=1,2,3...$ and $m\geq0, \ m=\mathrm{const}$. The coefficient $A_{m,j}$ is generated by
\begin{equation*}\label{gen_13}
A_{m,j}:=
\begin{cases}
0, & \mathrm{if } \ j<0 \ \mathrm{or } \ j>m \\
(2j+1)\binom{2j}{j} \sum_{d=2j+1}^{m} A_{m,d} \binom{d}{2j+1} \frac{(-1)^{d-1}}{d-j} B_{2d-2j}, & \mathrm{if } \ 0 \leq j < m \\
(2j+1)\binom{2j}{j}, & \mathrm{if } \ j=m \\
\end{cases}
\end{equation*}
Derivation of coefficients $A_{m,j}$ is discussed in [mathoverflow.net/questions/297900](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/297900/coefficients-in-the-sum-sum-k-0n-1-sum-j-0ma-j-mn-kjkj-n2m1). In particular, the right part of (1.3) returns odd power $2m+1$ of $T\in\mathbb{N}$ when $n=T$
\begin{equation*}
T^{2m+1}=\sum\limits_{0\leq k \leq m}(-1)^{m-k}U_m(T,k)\cdot T^k
\end{equation*}

**Detailed derivation of the polynomials, consisting the coefficient $U_m(n,k)$.**

Consider the identity discussed in [mathoverflow.net/questions/297900](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/297900/coefficients-in-the-sum-sum-k-0n-1-sum-j-0ma-j-mn-kjkj-n2m1),
\begin{equation}
n^{2m+1}=\sum\limits_{1\leq k \leq n}\sum\limits_{j\geq0}A_{m,j}k^j(n-k)^j,
\end{equation}
Let show a few examples of polynomials $\sum\nolimits_{j\geq0}A_{m,j}k^j(n-k)^j$ for $m=1,2,3$. We denote the part $\sum\nolimits_{j\geq0}A_{m,j}k^j(n-k)^j$ of the left part of equation (1.3) as
\begin{equation}\label{f4}
D_m(n,k)=\sum\limits_{j\geq0}A_{m,j}k^j(n-k)^j
\end{equation}
Therefore, for $m=1,2,3$ we have corresponding $D_m(n,k)$ as
\begin{equation}
(1.6)\quad\begin{cases}
D_{1}(n,k)=1+6k(n-k), & \\
D_{2}(n,k)=1-0k(n-k)+30k^2(n-k)^2, & \\
D_{3}(n,k)=1-14k(n-k)+0k^2(n-k)^2+140k^3(n-k)^3, & 
\end{cases}
\end{equation}
The coefficients in $D_{t=1,2,3}(n,k)$ are the terms of corresponding row of triangle https://oeis.org/A302971. Now, we show an example of generation of polynomials from the right part of (1.3) for $m=1$,

**Example 1.**

Let be $m=1$, then we rewrite the left hand side of  (1.3) as
\begin{equation}
(1.8)\quad\sum\limits_{1\leq k \leq T}\sum\limits_{j\geq0}A_{1,j}k^j(n-k)^j
\end{equation}
Next, let substitute the polynomial $D_1(n,k)$ from (1.6) into equation (1.8) and let be $T=1,...,10$, then
\begin{equation}
\sum\limits_{1\leq k \leq T}1+6k(n-k)=\begin{cases}
T=1 :& -5 + 6 n \\
  T=2 :& -28 + 18 n \\
  T=3 :& -81 + 36 n \\
  T=4 :& -176 + 60 n \\
  T=5 :& -325 + 90 n \\
  T=6 :& -540 + 126 n \\
  T=7 :& -833 + 168 n \\
  T=8 :& -1216 + 216 n \\
  T=9 :& -1701 + 270 n \\
  T=10:& -2300 + 330 n
\end{cases}
\end{equation}
Coefficients of above polynomials are terms of sequences [A028896](https://oeis.org/A028896) and [A275709](https://oeis.org/A275709).
Let show the case for $m=2$ and $T=1,...,10$, again we recall the corresponding polynomial $D_2(n,k)$ from (1.6) and substitute it into left part of (1.3),
\begin{equation}
\sum\limits_{1\leq k \leq T}1-0k(n-k)+30k^2(n-k)^2=\begin{cases}
T=1 :& 31 - 60 n + 30 n^2 \\
  T=2 :& 512 - 540 n + 150 n^2 \\
  T=3 :& 2943 - 2160 n + 420 n^2 \\
  T=4 :& 10624 - 6000 n + 900 n^2 \\
  T=5 :& 29375 - 13500 n + 1650 n^2 \\
  T=6 :& 68256 - 26460 n + 2730 n^2 \\
  T=7 :& 140287 - 47040 n + 4200 n^2 \\
  T=8 :& 263168 - 77760 n + 6120 n^2 \\
  T=9 :& 459999 - 121500 n + 8550 n^2 \\
  T=10:& 760000 - 181500 n + 11550 n^2
\end{cases}
\end{equation}
Similarly, let show an example for $m=3$ and $T=1,...,10$,
\begin{equation}
\sum\limits_{1\leq k \leq T}1-14k(n-k)+0k^2(n-k)^2+140k^3(n-k)^3=\begin{cases}
T=1 :&  -125 + 406 n - 420 n^2 + 140 n^3\\
  T=2 :&  -9028 + 13818 n - 7140 n^2 + 1260 n^3\\
  T=3 :&  -110961 + 115836 n - 41160 n^2 + 5040 n^3\\
  T=4 :&  -684176 + 545860 n - 148680 n^2 + 14000 n^3\\
  T=5 :&  -2871325 + 1858290 n - 411180 n^2 + 31500 n^3\\
  T=6 :&  -9402660 + 5124126 n - 955500 n^2 + 61740 n^3\\
  T=7 :&  -25872833 + 12182968 n - 1963920 n^2 + 109760 n^3\\
  T=8 :&  -62572096 + 25945416 n - 3684240 n^2 + 181440 n^3\\
  T=9 :&  -136972701 + 50745870 n - 6439860 n^2 + 283500 n^3\\
  T=10 :& -276971300 + 92745730 n - 10639860 n^2 + 423500 n^3
\end{cases}
\end{equation}
We can observe, that in every upper example, the resulting polynomial for every $m, T$ has the following form
\begin{equation}
\sum\limits_{0\leq k \leq m}(-1)^{m-k}U_m(n,k)\cdot n^k,
\end{equation}
Therefore, the following question is stated

**Question 1.** Is there a recurrent that gives the coefficients $U_m(n,k)$ otherwise then by the identity
\begin{equation}\label{f3_1}
\sum\limits_{1\leq k \leq T}\sum\limits_{j\geq0}A_{m,j}k^j(n-k)^j=\sum\limits_{0\leq k \leq m}(-1)^{m-k}U_m(n,k)\cdot n^k,
\end{equation}
i.e is there any function $F(n,m)$ such that $F(m,n)=U_m(n,k)$ but different from relation (1.3) ?

Above examples could be generated using Mathematica code [Um(n,k)_coefficients2.txt](https://kolosovpetro.github.io/mathematica_codes/Um(n,k)_coefficients2.txt). 
The [PDF-analog](https://kolosovpetro.github.io/pdf/OEIS_Um(n,k)_coefficients.pdf) of this question with extended data of $U_m(n,k)$ coefficients up to $T=40$ is available at this [link](https://kolosovpetro.github.io/pdf/OEIS_Um(n,k)_coefficients.pdf).

Comment: Something is wrong with (1.3) - the l.h.s. depends on $T$, while the r.h.s. does not.

Comment: @max-alekseyev, Thank you for your reply, right hand side doesn't depend on $T$ as right side is namely 'closed form' of summation from left side, the $k$ runs in $0\leq k \leq T$ which results a polynomial in $n$, without $T$.

Comment: One can verify results of (1.3) using Mathematica code https://kolosovpetro.github.io/mathematica_codes/Um(n,k)_coefficients2.txt .

Comment: I don't understand this. E.g., do you claim that the sum over $k$ with $1\leq k\leq 1$ (i.e., for $T=1$) is the same as the sum over $k$ with $1\leq k\leq 2$ (i.e., for $T=2$)? If so, then the summand for $k=2$ must be $0$.

Comment: In (1.3), shouldn't be $U_m(T,k)$ rather than $U_m(n,k)$ by any chance?

Comment: If we back to previous question (concerning $A_{m,j}$, mentioned in the beginning of the present question), we find an identity, $$n^{2m+1}=\sum_{k=1}^{n}\sum_{k=0}^{m}A_{m,j}k^j(n-k)^j$$. If we dont fix the upper limit of the first sum to be equal to variable $n$, but just let it be a some different value $T\in\mathbb{N}$, then we receive such polynomials, with respect to $m$ as well, for example, let be $m=2$ and $T=3$, then
$$=\sum_{k=1}^{T}\sum_{k=0}^{m}A_{m,j}k^j(n-k)^j=2943 - 2160 n + 420 n^2$$.

Comment: It is like a summation of polynomial $\sum_{j=0}^{m}A_{m,j}k^j(n-k)^j$ over $k$ from 1 to $T=1,2,3,4....$ but without susbtititing the corresponding $n=T$ to the resulting polynomial, i.e 
$$\sum\limits_{1\leq k \leq T}\sum\limits_{j\geq0}A_{m,j}k^j(n-k)^j=\sum\limits_{0\leq k \leq m}(-1)^{m-k}U_m(n,k)\cdot n^k,$$
and, as $n=T$ in $\sum\limits_{0\leq k \leq m}(-1)^{m-k}U_m(n,k)\cdot n^k$ it returns odd power, $T^{2m+1}$.

Comment: This still does not make sense to me.

Comment: @max-alexeyev, still doesn't make sense 'How we got polynomials' or 'Why we study them' ? For the second case, if we find the G.f. of $U_m(n,k)$ coeffcients, then another representation of odd power is reached, for instance, the formula mentioned in D. Knuth's https://arxiv.org/pdf/math/9207222.pdf on page 10 is likely we have in the right part of (1.3),
$$n^{2m+1}=\sum\limits_{1\leq k\leq m}(2k-1)!T(2m,2k)\binom{n+k-1}{2k-1},$$
I will clarify the statement of the problem to be easy understood everything concerning the derivations.

Comment: @MaxAlekseyev, the PDF version of this question is updated and available at https://kolosovpetro.github.io/pdf/OEIS_Um(n,k)_coefficients.pdf . Necessary details are added. The main question here will be updated accordingly soon.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First off, as I explained in the comments, the identity (1.3) should contain $U_m(T,k)$ rather than $U_m(n,k)$ (the latter does not make any sense), and so the correct identity (1.3) (for polynomials in $n$) states:
$$(1.3)\quad\sum_{k=1}^T\sum_{j=0}^m A_{m,j}k^j(n-k)^j\equiv \sum\limits_{0\leq k \leq m}(-1)^{m-k}U_m(T,k)\cdot n^k.$$
Also, to avoid confusion, it is important to notice that while coefficients $A_{m,j}$ come from the [previous question](https://mathoverflow.net/q/297900), there their indices are interchanged (i.e., $A_{j,m}$ instead of $A_{m,j}$).

Said that, it is not hard to express the polynomials $U_m(T,k)$ in terms of $A_{m,j}$ and Bernoulli numbers. To do so, let's expand the binomial $(n-k)^j$ in the l.h.s. of (1.3) and change of the order of summation:
\begin{split}
\sum_{k=1}^T\sum_{j=0}^m A_{m,j}k^j(n-k)^j &= \sum_{k=1}^T\sum_{j=0}^m A_{m,j}k^j\sum_{t=0}^j\binom{j}{t}n^t(-1)^{t-t}k^{j-t}\\
&=\sum_{t=0}^m n^t \sum_{k=1}^T\sum_{j=t}^m \binom{j}{t}A_{m,j}k^{2j-t}(-1)^{j-t}.
\end{split}
Now, taking the coefficient of $n^t$ in (1.3) gives:
$$U_m(T,t) = (-1)^m \sum_{k=1}^T\sum_{j=t}^m \binom{j}{t}A_{m,j}k^{2j-t}(-1)^j.$$

From this formula it may be not immediately clear why $U_m(T,t)$ represent polynomials in $T$. However, this can be seen if we change the summation order again and use Faulhaber's formula to obtain:
$$U_m(T,t) = (-1)^m \sum_{j=t}^m \binom{j}{t}A_{m,j} \frac{(-1)^j}{2j-t+1}\sum_{\ell=0}^{2j-t} \binom{2j-t+1}{\ell}B_{\ell}T^{2j-t+1-\ell}.$$
Introducing $k=2j-t+1-\ell$, we further get the formula:
$$U_m(T,t) = (-1)^m \sum_{k=1}^{2m-t+1} T^k \sum_{j=t}^m \binom{j}{t}A_{m,j} \frac{(-1)^j}{2j-t+1}\binom{2j-t+1}{k}B_{2j-t+1-k},$$
which allows easily compute the coefficient of $T^k$ in $U_m(T,t)$ for each $k$.

**N.B.** In the above formulae, we assume that $B_1=+\frac{1}{2}$.

Comment: Dear Dr. Alexeyev, your answer is totally correct and contains a details that I haven't noticed before, thank you for your time and power spent on this question, if you could be interested, you are welcome to revise (or add some info) to the sequences https://oeis.org/A316387 ($U_m(T,k), \ m=2$) https://oeis.org/A316387 ($U_m(T,k), \ m=3$)

Comment: Typos issue: https://oeis.org/A316349 ($U_m(T,k), \ m=2$.

Comment: @KolosovPetro: I've edited both sequences.